# TFS build server

Tags: msbuild, build-automation

We are just getting started with TFS 2010 and migration from SVN and CruiseControl.NET to TFS.

With cruisecontrol.NET we have a powershell script that does everything: copying, modifying, compressing files.

Now my question is how we can integrate that script into the TFS build server? Modifying the solution or creating a custom msbuild file?

Also I would like to combine this with Web Packaging. Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to create a custom msbuild file. In this file call build of your solution and then call your powershell script. Like:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="Build">
        <!-- Compile whole solution in release mode -->
        <MSBuild
            Projects="MySolutionFile.sln"
            Targets="ReBuild"
            Properties="Configuration=Release" />
<Exec
            Command=“command_for_run_cutom_script“
            ContinueOnError="false"
            WorkingDirectory="." />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

However consider rewriting your powershell script fully to msbuild script. You will get better maintenance. Copying, modifying, compressing files… are no problem for msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

http://tfsccnetplugin.codeplex.com/ has all the documentation you need in terms of Configuring CCNet with TFS, as for the web packaging...unfortunately someone else will have to help with that.